# Ionic exception when running any ionic command, how to?

Tags: javascript, cordova, npm, ionic2, ionic3

I'm getting this error when i run a ionic command `ionic ...`:

```
{ Error
    at FatalException.Exception (C:\Users\crist\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\@ionic\cli-utils\lib\errors.js:8:23)
    at FatalException (C:\Users\crist\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\@ionic\cli-utils\lib\errors.js:17:9)
    at Config.<anonymous> (C:\Users\crist\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\@ionic\cli-utils\lib\config.js:45:35)
    at throw (native)
    at rejected (C:\Users\crist\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:94:69) name: 'Exception', exitCode: 1, fatal: true }
```

I tried removing ionic and cordova, clearing cache and re-installing it, globally and in project, but still same error

any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you create a brand new project and see that?

Comment: Tried it. same error. I think this might be a global issue.

Comment: You can put that here: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/new

Comment: Added: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2761

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `~/.ionic/config.json` was corrupt. I removed the `~/.ionic` directory and reinstall it. Seems fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. 
Removing .ionic folder and reinstalling did resolve the error.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the .ionic folder then run the ionic command in the cli again

Answer (score 0):

from root on mac,for "jenkins" user 
chown -R jenkins ~/.npm/ and chown -R jenkins ~/.config/

and check ionic version by: ionic -v
3.20.0
fixed this!!